# Swiping between spaces changed

Tags: trackpad, spaces

A couple days ago, my MacBook updated to Mac OS X 10.13.2 (17C88), and since then, the swiping between spaces has been fickle.

Before the update, I just had to swipe with three fingers (as per the setting) and the screen with my mouse cursor would switch to the desire space.

Since the update, I occasionally have to click with the trackpad to initiate the switch.  Without clicking it does nothing.  However, once clicked it works without clicking for a while (like it did before).  Also, I don't have to hold the click; it's almost like a focus issue.

Is anyone else experience this?  Is this something Apple did in the update?  Is there a way to get the swipe to work without clicking again?

Comment: I don't have any problems swiping with 3 fingers between spaces.  Have you checked your Settings to ensure nothing has changed?

Comment: Yes, there are no settings regarding clicking during gestures.

Comment: I wasn't referring to clicking during the gesture, just that the gesture for 3-finger swiping between Spaces was still setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted and the behavior corrected itself.  Not sure what the cause was.